# Duplicated row when inserting data into Datagridview using SQL store procedure and C# error

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I want to update Datagridview insert new row if not existing record and update if existing record by using SQL procedure as below:
Edited

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PROC_PMS_Update]
        @INDEXNO nvarchar(50),
        @_PROCESS_INST_NO nvarchar(50),
        @_Order_No nvarchar(50),
        @_GOODS_CD  nvarchar(50),
        @_GOODS_NAME nvarchar(50),
        @_LINE_NO       int,
        @_UNIT nvarchar(50),
        @_QTY int       
    AS  
        UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] SET _GOODS_CD=@_GOODS_CD,_GOODS_NAME=@_GOODS_NAME,  _UNIT = @_UNIT,_QTY=@_QTY,
                [_UPDATE_DATE]=(select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111), 10))                      
                 WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO AND  _LINE_NO = @_LINE_NO 

     IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
        BEGIN
             INSERT INTO [TBL_PROC_PMS]([INDEXNO],[_PROCESS_INST_NO],[_Order_No],[_LINE_NO],[_GOODS_CD],[_GOODS_NAME],[_UNIT],[_QTY])   
                SELECT @INDEXNO, @_PROCESS_INST_NO,@_Order_No,@_LINE_NO,@_GOODS_CD,@_GOODS_NAME,@_UNIT,@_QTY  FROM [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] 
              WHERE @_LINE_NO NOT IN(SELECT _LINE_NO FROM [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO) AND _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO
        END
```

And here is C# button Save click:

```
 var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PROC_PMS_Update", sqlConn);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdMaterial.Rows)
                {                     
                    if (!item.IsNewRow)
                    {                           
                        cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
                        int rowindex = item.Index;
                        var _GOODS_CD = item.Cells[4].Value;
                        var _GOODS_NAME = item.Cells[5].Value;
                        var _UNIT = item.Cells[6].Value;
                        var _QTY = item.Cells[7].Value;
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INDEXNO", lblINDEX.Text);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_INST_NO", txtInstNo.Text);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_Order_No", txtPONo.Text);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_LINE_NO", rowindex);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GOODS_CD", _GOODS_CD);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GOODS_NAME", _GOODS_NAME);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_UNIT",_UNIT);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_QTY", _QTY);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

Before insert 1 new row:

[image]
Insert only 1 row :
[image]

But after saving, it duplicates 1 more row :

[image]

Comment: You are checking `!item.IsNewRow`. This will store all existing rows.

Comment: if not checking !item.IsNewRow. It will duplicate 6 rows

Comment: UPDATE ....  IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)  BEGIN   //do_insert  END

Comment: ...but personally, I don't like having a separate transaction for each line. If you do a larger form this way, you might end up (by nesting modules) on tens or maybe even hundreds of transactions, which will have a huge effect on it's performance.

Comment: Yes, mjwills is right, I made a mistake, use @@ROWCOUNT = 0 (equal sign). So if **nothing** is updated, **then** insert new row.

Comment: but it still insert duplicate row

Answer (score 4):

Rather than doing both an UPDATE *and* an INSERT like your existing stored proc does (which will **guarantee** at least one extra row is added), you should try one of two options.

- Only run the INSERT if the UPDATE had no effect (by checking `@@ROWCOUNT = 0`)
- Use a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: Duplicated row is my current problem, anyone help me! Thanks!

Comment: I have just updated my current code. Please see and help. My problem is it insert duplicate row

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by modifiyng this procedure:

```
 --UPDATE EXISTING RECORDS      
                    UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] SET _GOODS_CD=@_GOODS_CD,_GOODS_NAME=@_GOODS_NAME,  _UNIT = @_UNIT,_QTY=@_QTY,
                    [_UPDATE_DATE]=(select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111), 10))                      
                     WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO AND  _LINE_NO = @_LINE_NO 
        --INSERT NON-EXISTING RECORDS
         IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
            BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO [TBL_PROC_PMS]([INDEXNO],[_PROCESS_INST_NO],[_Order_No],[_LINE_NO],[_GOODS_CD],[_GOODS_NAME],[_UNIT],[_QTY],[_UPDATE_DATE])    
                 VALUES(@INDEXNO,@_PROCESS_INST_NO,@_Order_No,@_LINE_NO,@_GOODS_CD,@_GOODS_NAME,@_UNIT,@_QTY,(select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111), 10)))

            END
```